# Bridged Networking In KVM not working

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

i have tried all my very best to make KVM bridges networking work, but it is not so simple as in VMWare Workstation. All i want to do is to get a VM appear as a normal host on the LAN subnet (192.168.0.0/24), so it can ping my Home GW (192.168.0.1/24) and the Internet. After repeated attempts with setting up a bridge interface and binding it with my KVM Server's WLAN port (which causes my Internet connection to be lost if br1 interface is given a static address, but No configuration option works fine).

Please can some guide through this process. All this is being done on Ubuntu 16.10. i am trying to follow all this procedure from this image.

[image]

Waiting eagerly for your kind replies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces file for reference on getting a bridge setup for kvm.  Both the hypervisor and the vm's get their ipv4 addresses with dhcp and their ipv6 addresses with slaac.  The multicast_snooping line is only for ipv6.  This is all I had to do and it just worked with a wired connection.  **Bridging is not possible on most wlan connections** because most wlan drivers don't support it.  If it works on vmware, they're not using a standard bridge and I don't know if anyone has come up with a workaround for kvm.  I'm pretty sure you can use macvtap's with wlan but you can't use it for hypervisor to guest communication or for pxe booting from.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    up echo -n 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/multicast_snooping
```

Edit: Apparently there is a work around for bridging on wifi, see:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159198/213946

Comment: Ok will try ASAP...maybe WLAN interface issue......will give you feedback at the earliest

Comment: Can someone kindly tell what will be the Virtual Guest Network Settings for Bridged Networking, its should be my ADSL Router/Home Gateway/ LAN on which Guest is being Bridged to...correct? Moreover, what is this br0 ip address, is it like an SVI(Switched Virtual Interface) on the BR switch?